# Include single item from related table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have a table called `items` and a table called `item_pics`.

`item_pics` has an `item_id`, `file_name` and a `rank` field (among others).

---

**What I'm looking for** is for each `item` my `index` page's `$items` array to contain the `file_name` from the `item_pics` matching the `item`'s `item_id` with the lowest `rank`. So I can access like (or *something* like) this in my `Items/index.ctp`:

```
 foreach ($items as $item):
    $img = $item['Item']['ItemPic']['file_name'];
    ...
```

---

I'm pretty new to CakePHP, this is my first project. I thought that this within the `Item` model would cause `item_pics` data to be pulled (although I figured all related `item_pics` for each `item` would get pulled rather than just the one with the lowest `rank`):

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'ItemPic' => array(
        'className' => 'ItemPic',
        'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
        'dependent' => false
    )
}
```

but I can see that no `item_pics` data is loaded (at the bottom of `items/index`):

```
SELECT `Item`.`id`, `Item`.`title`, `Item`.`description`, `Item`.`created`, `Item`.`modified`, `Item`.`type`, `Project`.`id`, `Project`.`item_id`, `Project`.`title`, `Project`.`description`, `Project`.`rank`, `Project`.`created`, `Project`.`modified`
FROM `laurensabc`.`items` AS `Item`
LEFT JOIN `laurensabc`.`projects`
AS `Project`
ON (`Project`.`item_id` = `Item`.`id`)
WHERE `Item`.`type` IN (1, 2)
LIMIT 20
```

also, while I would like `projects` to be joined in the `view` pages, I don't really need them in the `index` page.

I've done some searching and haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for. I suppose I could do a query within the `index` view item loop, but I'm trying to make sure I do things the right way... the CakePHP way. I assume I need to change something about my model relationships but I haven't had any luck.

[CakePHP - Associations - HasMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany), this makes it seem like I could order by rank and limit 1. But this didn't work... and even if it did, I wouldn't want that to affect the `view` pages but rather just the `index` page.

My Controller looks like this:

```
public function index($type = null) {
    $this->Item->recursive = 0;
    $conditions = array();
    if ($type == "sale") {
        $conditions = array(
                "Item.type" => array(self::FOR_SALE, self::FOR_SALE_OR_RENT)
        );
    } else if ($type == "rent" ) {
        $conditions = array(
                "Item.type" => array(self::FOR_RENT, self::FOR_SALE_OR_RENT)
        );
    } else {
        $conditions = array("Item.type !=" => self::HIDDEN);
    }
    $paginated = $this->Paginator->paginate($conditions);
    debug($paginated);
    $this->set('items', $paginated);
    $this->set('title', ($type == null ? "Items for Sale or Rent" : "Items for " . ucwords($type)));
}
```

I have also tried this on my controller, but it doesn't seem to do anything either:

```
    $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'alias' => 'ItemPic',
                'table' => 'item_pics',
                'type' => 'left',
                'conditions' => array('ItemPic.item_id' => 'Item.id'),
                'order' => array('ItemPic.rank' => 'asc'),
                'limit' => 1
            )
        )
    );
    $paginated = $this->paginate($this->Item);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set `containable` behavior in AppModel (or if you don't want it on each model, put it on `Item` model):

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Then, on your find query:

```
$items = $this->Item->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'ItemPic' => array(
            'fields' => array('file_name'),
            'order' => 'rank',
            'limit' => 1
        )
    )
));
```

Then the result array you can access it like:

```
foreach ($items as $item):
    $img = $item['ItemPic']['file_name'];
```

**Edit:** Then you should put it on the paginate query:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'contain' => array(
        'ItemPic' => array(
            'fields' => array('file_name'),
            'order' => 'rank',
            'limit' => 1
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I don't have a find query, where would I put this?

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. Then you should put it on your `$this->paginate`, although I'm not 100% sure, as `paginate` is not equally exact as a find query and I haven't used it too much. But try it anyways. Look at my edit.

Comment: Seems to work, although it's in `$item['ItemPic'][0]['file_name']`. I'll have to look more into this `containable` feature... but in the meantime, do you know if there are any negatives to using it?

Comment: Oh, right, the index =_= negative uses...well...for some large queries with many associations it seems to be a bit suboptimal, but in exchange you get a simple and readable way to make the query and process the results :)

Comment: Note this: Containable will execute a query for every! row of your main table. so, if your "base" result-set count is 1000, cake will execute 1000 queries ... a 'simple' `find()` will use joins and since you have only one record to match (if i understood you correctly), it is preferred.

Comment: Could you show an alternative to `Containable`? Also, I don't think I can use `find()` if I am using `paginate()`?

Comment: `paginate` and `find` use the same kind of conditions, so there should be no problem. And if not, then you will have to stick to a) `recursive`, or b) `join` statement on your `options` array

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would probably order by rank and limit 1 as you said, and make that a dynamic association just for the index page (See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly).  So use `$this->Item->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array('ItemPic' => $options)));` (which I believe should replace your current settings for HasMany ItemPic, but you may have to unbindmodel first)

Associations created through bindModel will go through for the next query only, then it'll revert to your normal settings, unless you specifically set an option to keep using the new association.

As for why it's not getting ItemPics with Items, or why trying to order by rank and limit 1 didn't work for you, I can't really say without seeing more of your code.

Comment: I've added my Controller code for `index`, is there anything else you would like to see?